# Selenium - Eclipse: NullPointerException when running test suite

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am only facing an issue with NullPointerException when I tried to run a test suite with 2-3 test cases. However, if I run the test case individually, it runs well. Below is **BaseSetup** class.

```
 public class BaseSetup {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }       

    private void setDriver(String browserType, String appURL) {
        switch (browserType) {
        case "chrome":
            driver = initChromeDriver(appURL);
            break;
        case "firefox":
            driver = initFirefoxDriver(appURL);
            break;      
    }

    private static WebDriver initChromeDriver(String appURL) {
        ...
    }

    private static WebDriver initFirefoxDriver(String appURL) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to(appURL);
        return driver;
    }

    @Parameters({ "browserType", "appURL" })
    @BeforeSuite
    public void initializeTestBaseSetup(String browserType, String appURL) {
        try {
            setDriver(browserType, appURL);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error....." + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {}
```

This is **LoginPage** class (elements of the page)

```
public class LoginPage {

//web elements of login page
protected WebDriver driver;
private By txtUsername = By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']");
private By txtPassword = By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']");
private By btnlogin = By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginbutton']");
private String lblError = null;

//constructor
public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

//verify using incorrect password

//enter username into username textbox
public void enterUsername (String username){
    WebElement txtname = driver.findElement(txtUsername);
    if (txtname.isDisplayed())
    {
        txtname.sendKeys(username);
    }
}

//enter password into password textbox
public void enterPassword (String password){
    WebElement txtpw = driver.findElement(txtPassword);
    if (txtpw.isDisplayed())
    {
        txtpw.sendKeys(password);
    }
}

public void clickOnLoginBtn (){     
}
```

This is **LoginPageTest** class.

```
public class LoginPageTest extends BaseSetup {  

private WebDriver driver;
private LoginPage loginPage;

@Test
public void verifyLoginFunction() {   

  loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);    
  loginPage.enterUsername("abcdef"); //log trace the error here
  loginPage.enterPassword("abcdef");
  loginPage.clickOnLoginBtn();

}  
@BeforeClass
public void Setup() {
  driver=getDriver();
}   
}
```

This is **VerifyErrorMessage** class (2nd case)

```
  private WebDriver driver;
  private LoginPage loginPage;

  @Test
  public void verifyLoginMessage() {          
      loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);                  
      loginPage.enterUsername("abc");
      loginPage.clickOnLoginBtn();        
      String errorMsg = loginPage.getErrorMessage();
      System.out.println(errorMsg);
  }


  @BeforeClass
  public void Setup() {
      driver=getDriver();       
  }
}
```

This is Error in TestNG.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.facebook.objects.LoginPage.enterUsername(LoginPage.java:56)
    at com.facebook.tests.LoginPageTest.verifyLoginFunction(LoginPageTest.java:28)
... Removed 25 stack frames
```

So I ran **VerifyErrorMessage** first, then **LoginPageTest** later. Error trace is in comment of block code above.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the line of code for the `NullReferenceException` this line?

```
WebElement txtname = driver.findElement(txtUsername);
```

If so, then it's the `driver` variable that's `null`.  So in order to fix this you need to trace in your code where that becomes `null`.

Given the symptoms I would guess the issue is that you are initializing the driver only on beforeSuite, which works OK for the first test but the second+ test will get a null when getting the driver.  I don't see what your teardown method (`@AfterTest`) does so it's hard to verify but I'm guessing you set the driver to null there?

Try changing the `@BeforeSuite` to `@BeforeTest` and see if that fixes the issue:

```
@Parameters({ "browserType", "appURL" })
@BeforeSuite
public void initializeTestBaseSetup(String browserType, String appURL) {
    try {
        setDriver(browserType, appURL);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error....." + e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Or... if you are indeed setting driver to null in the teardown method with the `@AfterTest` annotation, you should change that to `@AfterSuite` instead.